# Golang JSON marshaling converts emoji to question mark

Tags: mysql, json, go

I have a golang web server which communicates with a MySQL database. Users can post comments, and these comments can contain emoji, among other utf8mb4 characters. My database is capable of storing and retrieving these emoji characters, however, when JSON marshaling / unmarshmaling, emoji are mangled. Is is possible to use Go's native encoding/json package to decode / encode utf8mb4 characters? If so, how would I go about doing so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you just [un]marshal the values as []byte and not worry about encoding at all?

Comment: Can you include an example of what is getting mangled?

Comment: @JimB's suggestion is probably as good as it's gonna get for you. I spent a few minutes reviewing the json package after reading your question and I just don't see anyway you can specify the encoding as `utf8mb4`.

Comment: What mysql driver do you use? Does your driver support charset=utf8mb4? Did you set it? There is nothing special about 4 bytes UTF-8 encoding (utf8mb4), go supports it out of the box. Use build in json.Encoder/Decoder

Comment: it handles single-, double-, triple-, and quad-bytes unicode codepoints https://play.golang.org/p/IhD66l32-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was eventually able to find a workaround. Previously I was marshaling the JSON into a []byte and then calling w.Write(jsonBytes) on my http.ResponseWriter. By casting the bytes to a string, writing the appropriate content type header and using io.WriteString instead I was able to prevent the mangling. Here is my code:

```
returnJSON, error := json.Marshal(value)
if error != nil { Error(w, error); return }
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
io.WriteString(w, string(returnJSON))
```

Comment: Simply adding `charset=utf-8"` was enough to resolve the issue for me. No need to cast to string :)

`w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")`

Comment: @KurtFunai is right, just setting the charset worked for me too. This is really surprising that it required that.